# How vuejs app appearing on google search results?

Tags: vue.js, seo, vuejs3, google-search

I have a VueJs application

The server returns

[image]

and I'm able to see my website listed on google
[image]

How it is possible?
As far as I understood Google will not be able to show if the website doesn't have the right tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is able to parse any SPA (even tho, it will not give the best rankings for something JS only).
In your first screenshot we can see that you're loading an `index.js` file (your Vue app), so if you have it hosted + exposed on a URL like https://musiccart.store/, yep Google will crawl it and make it available to everybody.

Not sure what you mean by **tags**, but by default: nothing more is required by Google to crawl your website.
You could have used a [robots.txt file](https://searchfacts.com/robots-txt-allow-disallow-all/) or host it somewhere protected with a password (or just behind a sneaky URL preview like on Netlify).